# How do you maintain a dict that is sorted by its values?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

[blist](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/sorteddict.html) provides a dictionary sorted by its keys, but I would like one sorted by values (I don't care about ordering of tied values).

I've tried the following, but it blows up with `KeyError: 1`.

```
from blist import sorteddict
d = sorteddict(lambda k: d[k])
d[1] = 5       # KeyError: 1
```

So how do I achieve this properly?

Comment: Are you sure there's a key of `1` in whatever dictionary `sorteddict` returns? Hint: you shouldn't be sure, because there isn't.

Comment: @khelwood - Sorting a dictionary by value is pretty common, like `collections.Counter.most_common` does.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Neat.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this is what you were looking for?

For example, assume you have a dictionary:

```
dictionary = {1:2, 2:0, 3:-1}
```

Then, you can re-order the keys by the value. In this example, I'm going to re-order this in ascending order.

```
dict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key = lambda x: dictionary[x[0]]))
```

You will get:

```
{3: -1, 2: 0, 1: 2}
```